# Looping SELECT statement for repetative columnnames

Tags: mysql, sql, database, loops

I tried to search on Google and Stackoverflow for a solution for bulky code. For a MySQL database I want to retrieve a big bulk of data. This database is not designed by ourselves but a external company so I cannot be held responsible for the lack of database engineering skill.

The problem is that I have to select 52 columns which all have a columnname with incrementing number (as can be seen in example).

```
SELECT results.tc_serial AS "SerialNo",
results.total_result AS "TotalResult",
results.eval_01_id AS "Measurement1_ID",

eval1_parameter.tag AS "Measurement1_TAG",
eval_result1.value AS "Measurement1_VAL",
eval2_parameter.tag AS "Measurement2_TAG",
eval_result2.value AS "Measurement2_VAL",
eval3_parameter.tag AS "Measurement3_TAG",
eval_result3.value AS "Measurement3_VAL",
eval4_parameter.tag AS "Measurement4_TAG",
eval_result4.value AS "Measurement4_VAL",
eval5_parameter.tag AS "Measurement5_TAG",
eval_result5.value AS "Measurement5_VAL",
eval6_parameter.tag AS "Measurement6_TAG",
eval_result6.value AS "Measurement6_VAL"

FROM ga_35_4599_ipc_01.test_results results 

JOIN ga_35_4599_ipc_01.test_parameters test_parameter ON
results.test_parameter_id = test_parameter.id

JOIN ga_35_4599_ipc_01.eval_windows_results eval_result1 ON
results.eval_01_id = eval_result1.id
JOIN ga_35_4599_ipc_01.eval_windows_results eval_result2 ON
results.eval_02_id = eval_result2.id
JOIN ga_35_4599_ipc_01.eval_windows_results eval_result3 ON
results.eval_03_id = eval_result3.id
JOIN ga_35_4599_ipc_01.eval_windows_results eval_result4 ON
results.eval_04_id = eval_result4.id
JOIN ga_35_4599_ipc_01.eval_windows_results eval_result5 ON
results.eval_05_id = eval_result5.id
JOIN ga_35_4599_ipc_01.eval_windows_results eval_result6 ON
results.eval_06_id = eval_result6.id



JOIN ga_35_4599_ipc_01.eval_windows_para eval1_parameter ON
test_parameter.eval_01_id = eval1_parameter.id
JOIN ga_35_4599_ipc_01.eval_windows_para eval2_parameter ON
test_parameter.eval_02_id = eval2_parameter.id
JOIN ga_35_4599_ipc_01.eval_windows_para eval3_parameter ON
test_parameter.eval_03_id = eval3_parameter.id
JOIN ga_35_4599_ipc_01.eval_windows_para eval4_parameter ON
test_parameter.eval_04_id = eval4_parameter.id
JOIN ga_35_4599_ipc_01.eval_windows_para eval5_parameter ON
test_parameter.eval_05_id = eval5_parameter.id
JOIN ga_35_4599_ipc_01.eval_windows_para eval6_parameter ON
test_parameter.eval_06_id = eval6_parameter.id


order by results.time desc
limit 10;
```

Is there a way to loop trough a SELECT in a way such as:

```
FOR (INT i = 1; i <= 52; i++)

SELECT Column_[i]
FROM tstDatabase
```

Once again, if I looked over some perfect example, I apologize. I'm also not a (My)SQL genius, as you can see by my code.

Comment: You can dynamically prepare this SQL query string in your application code (eg: PHP, Java, C++ etc)

Comment: If you know the actual `Column_` name, then what would be wrong with just building the query you want using cut-and-paste?

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns (above,say, '2'), you can be SURE that your design is seriously flawed. See normalisation.

Comment: @Strawberry I know the design is flawed, I already mentioned this. Unfortunately this is not possible to be changed.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I have to do this trough query only, there is no application. A application called MiniTab is executing the query and then analyzing the result data. Maybe a Stored Procedure example?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't mind doing this, but i've you have to copy the same statement 26 times, you're doing something wrong in my opinion. I will update the post with the exact current query

Comment: To my way of thinking, MySQL is about the storage a nd retrieval of normalised data. If you're not going to bother with normalisation, then you may as well not bother with MySQL. So I reject the premise of the question.

Comment: this application and joined by MySQL is written by a external machinebuilder, we are a production facility. We have no acces to the code nor do we have root access to the MySQL DB. I know that normalization is the way to go but we can't, it not a matter of wanting. but if you are not keen on helping me than I suggest you keep the thread clean for those who do want to help, I'm sorry @Strawberry